# Need help finding GCD (noob approach)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently going through Math adventures with Python book by Peter Farrel. Now I am simply trying to improve my math skills while learning Python in a fun way. So we made a factors function as seen below:

```
def factors(num):
   factorList = []
   for i in range(1, num+1):
       if num % i == 0:
           factorList.append(i)
   return factorList
```

Exercise 3-1 is asking to make GCF (Greatest Common Factor) function. All the answers here are how we could use builtin Python modules or recursive or Euclid algorithm. I have no clue what any of these things mean, let alone trying it on this assignment. I came with the following solution using the above function:

```
def gcFactor(num1, num2):
    fnum1 = factors(num1)
    fnum2 = factors(num2)
    gcf = list(set(fnum1).intersection(fnum2))
    return max(gcf)

print(gcFactor(28,21))
```

Is this the best way of doing it? Using the `.intersection()` function seems a little cheaty to me.

So what I wanted to do is if I could use a loop and separate the list values in `fnum1` & `fnum2` and compare them and then return the value that matches (which would make common factors) and is greatest (which would be GCF).

Comment: "Builtin" means using `math.gcd`.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks for the tips. I only started learning programming 2 days ago. And yes I didn't wanna use math.gcd as I am trying to practice math problems with python for now. The book is moving in that direction. I don't want to just use a calculator to solve the problems for me. For now, I understand what intersection() does and it achieves the goal but was hoping for a better solution other than the Algorithms

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind your algorithm is sound, but there are a few problems:

- In your original version, you used `gcf[-1]` to get the greatest factor, but that will not always work, since converting a `set` to `list` does not guarantee that the elements will be in sorted order, even if they were sorted before converting to `set`. Better use `max` (you already changed that).
- Using `set.intersection` is definitely not "cheating" but just making good use of what the languages provides. It might be considered cheating to just use [`math.gcd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd), but not basic `set` or `list` functions.
- Your algorithm is rather inefficient. I don't know the book, but I don't think you should actually *use* the `factors` function to calculate the `gcf`, but that was just an exercise to teach you stuff like loops and modulo. Consider two very different numbers as inputs, say 23764372 and 6. You'd calculate all the factors of 23764372 first, before testing the very few values that could actually be common factors. Instead of using `factors` directly, try to rewrite your `gcFactor` function to test which values up to the `min` of the two numbers are factors of *both* numbers.
- Even then, your algorithm will not be very efficient. I would suggest reading up on [Euclid's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) and trying to implement that next. If unsure if you did it right, you can use your first function as a reference for testing, and to see the difference in performance.
- About your `factors` function itself: Note that there is a symmetry: if `i` is a factor, so is `n//i`. If you use this, you do not have to test all the values up to `n` but just up to `sqrt(n)`, which is a speed-up equivalent to reducing running time from O(n²) to O(n).